# How do I eliminate the gap on the right of an input box within a TD

Tags: html, css

Consider this simple HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- Table for reference purposes -->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="width: 200px">
    <tr>
        <td>100px</td>
        <td>100px</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="width: 200px">
    <tr>
        <td><input style="width:100px"/></td>
        <td>100px</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The table on the top is for reference only, so you can see what I expect.  In the table at the bottom there is a large gap to the right of the input.  Why is it there, and how can I get rid of it without reducing the size of the input too much?

Thanks,
Stephen

Some of you have answered that I should set the width of the TD's, so I've done this, but the two tables still don't line up.  How can I fix this without reducing the size of the input too much?  (I don't want the gap on the right of the input)

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- Table for reference purposes -->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="width: 200px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:100px">100px</td>
        <td style="width:100px">100px</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="width: 200px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:100px"><input style="width:90px"/></td>
        <td style="width:100px">100px</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I've uploaded this example to http://losthobbit.net/temp/testx.html temporarily, so you can see exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: Can you attach an image with a highlight? I am not sure what you are asking about exactly.

Comment: For an example, see losthobbit.net/temp/testx.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem:  Reduce the size of the TD's, keeping the tables the same width, e.g:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="width: 200px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:97px"><input style="width:90px"/></td>
        <td style="width:97px">100px</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `<input>` elements have extra padding, borders, and margins that make it wider than what you say it should be. You can either remove the extra stuff so that the input is flush with the table cell, or make the width of your input smaller.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Can you please be more specific?  I've tried removing padding, but haven't been able to get it right yet.

Comment: I don't want to lose the border.  I've tried the following, which doesn't work: <td style="width:100px;margin-right:0px;"><input style="width:90px;margin-right:0px;"/></td>

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it lined up with the following HTML on the second table:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="width: 200px">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td><input style="width:97px;margin:0 !important;padding:0; float: left;"></td>
        <td style="width:100px">100px</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Nice one! :)  I already found a solution to my problem, which I've pasted below,... but I'll mark yours as correct for finding a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not
`<td><input style="width:90px"/></td>`

Or

`<td><input size="11"></td>`

Comment: I derived `size="11"` from typing capital `M` until i reached the right edge.

Comment: Okay, I tried that and I get a better result, but the top and bottom tables are still not aligned. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Set the width on the first `<td>` in the table.

```
<td style="width:100px;">
```

Comment: Okay, I tried that and I get a better result, but the top and bottom tables are still not aligned. Any ideas?

Comment: Your reference table's td are not 100px, add the style="width:100px" to your reference table td and you'll see what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

Since u have specified a fixed width for the table, I think the first table cell will try to take up the maximum space. If u have to specify a table width, then specify a width for the cell too.. that way the space wont appear

Comment: Okay, I tried that and I get a better result, but the top and bottom tables are still not aligned.  Any ideas?

Comment: thats because the top and bottom tables are 2 separate tables. They have nothing to do with eachother. If u want the cells to be aligned, why dont u create rows and specify a width for the first cell of the first row. The remaining rows will follow suit.

Comment: The above is a highly simplified version of what it is that I want to do.  I need two tables so that the bottom table can scroll vertically independently of the top table.

Comment: in dat case give the same width for the first cells of both the tables .. dsnt that work ?

Comment: I've tried that, and edited the description of this question so that you can see.  They are still not aligned.

Comment: delete the "style='width:100px'" from the 2nd cells for each table. It will align in place...

Comment: Thanks Lin.  I've posted a way of making it work without modifying the reference table, but what you're saying makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="width: 200px">
    <tr>
        <td>100px</td>
        <td>100px</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="width: 200px">
<col span="2" width="100px">
    <tr>
        <td><input style="width:95%"></td>
        <td>100px</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

using `<col>` to set the widths then reducing the input width to a smaller percentage to allow room for it's borders and padding makes the two tables line up  for me

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  I have managed to resolve my problem and posted it, and if I'm not mistaken your solution is out by a single pixel.

Comment: yes it is out by pixel, thought you wanted gap reducing not pixel perfect ;) - anyhow change the percentage to 96% for the input and it's golden **across browser**. Your own solution (sorry never saw it before I posted mine) is out by 3-4px on Firefox and Safari, though OK in IE.. the literal counting method may work against you cross browser

Comment: Strange... I've tested my solution in IE, Chrome & FireFox 4.01, and it works pixel perfectly:  http://losthobbit.net/temp/testx.html